# Can I reset the horizontal position to the current line's absolute left?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, positioning, paragraphs

I want to set the current text / box insertion point to the point where the current line originally started, no matter where I am on that line. Ordinarily, this would mean I would start overlaying text on existing text, but I'm drawing a pyramid shape (a syntactic tree), and know that the text won't actually overlap, though the bounding boxes do.

The effect would be something like `\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\\`, but is there a better way?

**Edit**

Here's a MWE of my layout (the frames and `\hrule`s are intended to help visualize the margins and aid in debugging). (1) demonstrates the default indentation that linguex imposes. (2) is what I get with the default. (3) is what I want, but I'd like to be able to achieve this without the `\hskip-\Exlabelwidth\hskip-\Exlabelsep` hack. Is there some (La)TeX primitive to do this without having to know where I am on the line?

[image: Linguex examples]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[vmargin=.25in,hmargin=.5in,paperwidth=4.6in,paperheight=6.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{linguex}
\AtBeginDocument{\settowidth{\Exlabelwidth}{(2)}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds} % for [framed] option
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\newcommand{\drawtree}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[framed,baseline={([yshift={-\ht\strutbox}]current bounding box.north)}]%
    \tikzset{level distance=22pt, every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}%
    \Tree [.CP
        [.DP {D\\The}
          [.NP {N\\horse}
            [.CP {C\\{[that]}}
              [.VP
                [.V$'$ \edge[roof]; {[was] raced past} ]
                [.DP {D\\the}
                  [.NP \edge[roof]; {barn} ]]]]]]
        [.VP {V\\fell} ]]
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

Consider the following basic example:

\ex. The horse raced past the barn fell.

Consider also its tree form:

\medskip\hrule

\ex. \drawtree

Or, properly centered on the page:

\medskip\hrule

\ex. \hskip-\Exlabelwidth\hskip-\Exlabelsep\hfil\drawtree\hfil

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a Minimum Working Example (MWE). Especially given that you are drawing rather than in standard text mode.

Comment: If you know for sure you're at the beginning of the line, you can write text and go back to the beginning of the line wi the `\rlap{ some text}` command.

Comment: If you are inside the paragraph and you need to print something at the start of current line, use `\vadjust` primitive. But your question is not clear (and it is without example), so I do nothing more explicit.

Comment: If boxes overlap, then you have to use some sort of overlay trick.  For vertical overlap \raisebox{1.6\baselineskip}[0pt]{...} is probably best.    For horizontal overlap, \hspace{\dimexpr \linewidth-\textwidth} works for any list environment.